# Prevent route change within Vue compnent

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Is it possible to prevent a route change within a Vue Component (not within my router file)?

My situation uses the same component, but the URL changes (`/users/1` -> `/users/2`)

```
Vue.extend({
  data: () => ({
     active: true
  }),
  beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next){
     if (this.active) {
        // do not redirect
     } else {
        next();
     }
  }
})
```

My understanding is that this doesn't work when navigating the URL but the View/Component stays the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I need to use `beforeRouteUpdate` instead of `beforeRouteLeave` as stated in the [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards)

```
beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
    if (this.active) {
      next(false);
    } else {
      next();
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm using beforeRouteUpdate route url path in the browser not getting update, so I used beforeRouteLeave which is **updating url** and **stop reloading** same page.

```
beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
    if (this.active) {
      next(false);
    } else {
      next();
    }
}
```